# How to get title of first tab of android tab-layout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I am able to get title of other tabs using OnTabSelectedListener.
However OnTabSelectedListener not getting called for first tab at first time.

I am using below code to get title:

[image]

Kindly help me.

Comment: what about `tabLayout.getTabAt(0)` ?

Comment: @RadekJ, yes it's working with tabLayout.getTabAt(0). Unable to understand which listener get called first time.

Comment: I think that for the first time the `dispatchTabSelected` is called there is no any listeners yet.

Maybe try to add your listener before any data is added to tabLayout?

Comment: Sure, I will try this too. Thank you so much :)